# Idea on how to insert a data from a transaction on pos system to database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I already have known about how to insert, update, delete value to and from database. One thing I doubt is that in POS it has multiple transaction in one entry, how would I do saving the transaction in the database? How it will work, just need an idea? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a relational database set up to do this in the best way. Basically, you would have 3 tables:

- products
- transactions
- product_transaction

The last table is a pivot table. It relates the products to the transactions, since a transaction can have multiple products and vice versa.

In the `products` table, you would have these columns:

- id (id of the product, auto-incrementing)
- any other details you want to store (category, name, description, price, etc.)

In the `transactions` table, you would have these columns:

- id (id of the transaction, auto-incrementing)
- any other details you want to store (customer_id, date, grand_total, etc.)

Finally, the `product_transaction` is a pivot table. It has only 2 columns:

- id (auto-incrementing)
- product_id
- transaction_id

You would have to create a relational link from `product_id` to the `id` of the products table, and from `transaction_id` to the `id` of the transactions table.

---

So, when a transaction is done, first, you would create a new transaction and insert it into the transactions table. Get the id of the inserted row and store it in a variable.

```
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect('host','username','password','database');

  $productIds = $_REQUEST['product_ids'];

  # totally unnecessary, but it calculates grand
  # total, in case you need that for your project
  $grandTotal = 0;
  foreach($productIds as $productId) {
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `price` from `products` WHERE `id`={$productId}");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $grandTotal += $row[0];
  }

  # insert new row, with whatever details you may want
  $query = mysqli_query($con, "
    INSERT INTO
    `transactions`(`date`,`grand_total`)
    VALUES(TODAY(), {$grand_total})
  ");

  # get its id
  $transactionId = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

Next, for each of the products you need to create an entry in the pivot table.

```
  # get its id
  $transactionId = mysqli_insert_id($con);

  foreach($productIds as $productId) {
    # create entry in table
    mysqli_query($con, "
      INSERT INTO
      `product_transaction`(
        `product_id`,
        `transaction_id`
      ) VALUES(
        {$productId},
        {$transactionId}
      )
    ");

    # also do other stuff here, like
    # maybe updating the stock value
  }
?>
```

And, yay! You're done!

---

To retrieve the data, you would only need the transaction id. Since you set up a relational database, the next step is a breeze and can be done with a few queries.

```
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect('host','username','password','database');

  $transactionId = # whatever the id is

  # get transaction details
  $transactionQuery = mysqli_query($con, "
    SELECT *
    FROM `transactions`
    WHERE `id`={$transactionId} 
  ");

  $transaction = mysqli_fetch_assoc($transactionQuery);

  # the query to fetch the products
  $productsQuery = mysqli_query($con, "
    SELECT `products`.*
    FROM `product_transaction`
    WHERE `transaction_id`={$transactionId}
    JOIN `products`
    ON `product_transaction`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
  ");

  # create and populate array of products
  $products = Array();
  while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productsQuery)) {
    $products[] = $product;
  }
?>
```

So, that last query uses the *relational* part of the MySQL Relational Database Management System (RDBMS). In English, it means,

```
select everything in the products table
where the transaction id of `product_transaction` is whatever.
however, since i'm linking 2 tables,
find the product where its id is equal to the product id of this row.
merge the two separate rows into one resultant row and give it to me.
```

[This link explains it MUCH better than I can.](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)

You now have the transaction details in `$transaction`, and the products in `$products`. You could take this even further by doing

```
$transaction['products'] = $products;
```

at the end. So then if you wanted the first product in the transaction, you could do `$transaction['products'][0]`. Much more convenient.

I normally don't ask for votes, but this answer took forever to write. So pretty please?

Comment: Sure thing @Romeo! Let me know if you need help with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need is for the POS to send the data to a PHP script. Then you save the received data to a TXT file and you use it as a starting point to treat it. There's not much we can do with out the input at this point.

1. Figure out how the POS can communicate with the PHP script
2. Create a temporary PHP script that will save the received data into a txt file
3. Use the txt file to create a code that will save it the way you want
4. Replace the temporary php code with the php saving code
5. Test every transaction to make sure it works for every variations